# Thymeleaf View Resolver not working when deploying spring boot application in weblogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, weblogic

**Getting Error in weblogic console:-**

```
116820 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] Exception processing template "resources-data": Error resolving template [resources-data], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [resources-data], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

While running from Tomcat it working fine.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ses.rest.utility</groupId>
    <artifactId>response-to-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>response-to-html</name>
    <description>response-to-html</description>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Not required when run in Weblogic -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


**weblogic.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>


**application.properties**

server.port=8096
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false  
spring.thymeleaf.suffix: .html  
logging.level.root = INFO
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

ServletInitializer.java

package com.rest.responsetohtml;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ResponseToHtmlClient.class);
    }

}

**ResponseToHtmlClient.java**

package com.rest.responsetohtml;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ResponseToHtmlClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResponseToHtmlClient.class, args);
    }
}


**ResponseToHtmlController.java**

package com.rest.responsetohtml.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.rest.responsetohtml.service.ResponseToHtmlService;
import com.rest.responsetohtml.vo.ResourcesData;

@Controller
public class ResponseToHtmlController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseToHtmlController.class);

    @Autowired
    ResponseToHtmlService responseToHtmlService;

    @GetMapping("/v100/getHtmlPage")
    public ModelAndView getData(@RequestParam String serviceId) {

        logger.info(" INSIDE ResponseToHtmlController => ");
        logger.info(" url => " + serviceId);
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        ResourcesData service = responseToHtmlService.getResourcesData(serviceId);

        if (service != null) {
            logger.info(" service response recieved ");
            modelAndView.setViewName("resources-data");
            modelAndView.addObject("service", service);
            modelAndView.addObject("html", service.html);
        } else {
            logger.info(" service response not received ");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

}


**resources-data.html**

<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add CSS and JS to Thymeleaf</title>
    <link th:href="@{/index.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<span th:utext="${html}"></span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources ID :</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.name}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources Name:</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.name}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources Base Type:</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.baseType}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources Life Cycle State:</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.lifecycleState}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources Type:</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.type}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Resources Href:</h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${service.href}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Used View Resolved Configuration which solves above issue. @Configuration
public class ThyeamleafViewConfig

Comment: @Bean
 SpringResourceTemplateResolver xmlTemplateResolver(ApplicationContext appCtx) {
  SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

  templateResolver.setApplicationContext(appCtx);
  templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
  templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
  templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
  templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

  return templateResolver;
 }

Comment: @Bean(name = "springTemplateEngine")
 SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ApplicationContext appCtx) {
  SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
  templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(xmlTemplateResolver(appCtx));
  return templateEngine;
 }